# Not able to access EC2 instance in same VPC via private IP

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, windows-firewall

I have 2 EC2 instances (one window and one linux) in same subnet. I am trying to access one instance from another via private IP but I am not able to do so.

In security groups, both instances belong to same security groups and security group allows all traffic from the same security group.

I am not even able to ping one instance from another using private IP address.

Any pointers what could be wrong here.

Comment: Did you allow ICMP? It's blocked by default.

Comment: Initially I had only one rule with All traffic but that didn't work. Then i created ICMP rule as well but that also didn't work.

Comment: Is it both directions or just one? Have you disabled Windows firewall?

Comment: Please use `telnet [domainname or ip] [port]`, e.g. `telnet 192.168.1.1 443`

Comment: @ChrisWilliams, It worked. I disabled windows firewall and things are now working as expected. Thanks. Please write it down as answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will likely be the result of Windows firewall being enabled, with default settings it will block ping access (among other things).

Disabling it should enable inbound/outbound access to work for ping. This is a temporary measure and should not be considered a permanent workaround.

You should enable whitelisting in the Windows firewall to allow the ports you would like inbound or outbound to have network access to/from other resources within the network.

More information is available in [this link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/allow-pings-icmp-echo-request-through-your-windows-vista-firewall/).

Comment: MisterSmiths answer should be accepted as the correct answer in my opinion as it provides a better solution

Answer (score 2):

By default the Windows firewall will deny all inbound requests (including ping), but the firewall also contains a list of Exceptions (otherwise it would block everything!). Those Exceptions are a set of rules that describe what connections should be allowed in out-of-the-box.

To allow any additional connections, you just add a new rule to the firewall. There is a Wizard in the Windows Firewall GUI for viewing and creating rules, but i find it easier to use a PowerShell one-liner like this to allow ping:

`New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Inbound LAN Ping" -Direction Inbound -Protocol ICMPv4 -IcmpType 8 -RemoteAddress 192.168.1.0/24 -Action Allow`

Above will allow any IP's between `192.198.1.1 ... 192.168.1.255` to send ping requests to your Windows host (all other `RemoteAddress` will still be ignored). I'm assuming here your Linux machine's IP is for example `192.168.1.1` and your Windows machine's IP is `192.168.1.123`.

As a rule of thumb, you should only open up the minimal number of ports, to as few IP/IP ranges as possible.